# Typescript stopped working with absolute paths

Tags: node.js, typescript

I'm maintain a fork of a repo, during my last update I applied changes however now typescript will not recognize absolute pathing.

I've made no changes to my `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noEmit": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": false,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "types": ["jest", "node"],
    "useUnknownInCatchVariables": false
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "cypress"],
  "include": ["src/**/*"]
}
```

However now the compiler doesn't recognize paths that looks like so:

```
import { useIsDarkMode } from 'state/user/hooks'
```

Comment: You need to provide more details including the error message you are getting, and whether if you check out an older version it compiles again. If you can, you can use `git blame` to isolate the commit that introduced the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Something went wrong with the node_modules, after I deleted them and called

```
yarn clean cache
yarn
```

Then everything started to work again